# Azure WebJob Schedule Error - ETAG

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Trying to publish a webjob from Visual Studio 2013, but I'm getting the following error in the output window:

```
Error   14  An error occurred while creating the WebJob schedule: BadRequest: The condition specified by the ETag is not satisfied.
```

The job is being published as an "on demand" type instead of "scheduled".

Ideas?

[image]

Comment: If you get this error from PowerShell - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27964254/an-error-occurred-while-creating-the-webjob-schedule/29268036#29268036

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the program managers on the product and this feature in VS is important to me so I'd like to help you work through this. Any chance, is your code available so we could attempt a repro of the error you're seeing?

Comment: I'm happy to help and to be assisted. Please find the project in the following Sky Drive link: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=67AEB702CE7FEBCD!1047&authkey=!APej1SoiNQi5Bsc&ithint=folder%2ccs

Comment: Quick question on this. Have you already deployed your site to a region and now you're trying to deploy it to a different region? Any more information you have on the workflow would be helpful. Also - the link to your file appears dead, I can't get to it any more.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=67AEB702CE7FEBCD!1141&authkey=!AD_DYqKWmOAb3LA&ithint=folder%2ccs

Comment: I already have a deployed website and haven't done anything but to add the given Webjob to it. What I have done, is adding \ removing the Webjob using VS & Azure web management system.

Comment: Also, I see the message in the Azure portal: The provided job collection region 'East US 2' is not supported. List of supported regions is 'South Central US,North Central US,North Europe,West Europe,East Asia,Southeast Asia,West US,East US,Japan West,Japan East,Brazil South'.

Comment: Please see the image I attached to the question above.

Comment: I looked at the image and spoke with a few folks on the error you're seeing. I *think* this is being caused because you have 2 free Scheduler Job Collections. Could you delete one of those and see if it works? Or, delete both of them and then re-deploy your WebJob (thus, re-creating the scheduler job collection for it). I'd like to see if this unblocks the issue.

Comment: Thanks allot for trying to help. I have tried to delete the second Job collection but still no change, also after redeploying everything. What did the trick eventually (yey!) is deploying the website at a different region: It was deployed under East US2, and now when I have deployed it to South Central US, everything works.

Comment: @bradygaster I keep running into this error for region North Europe. Nothing suggested in this question is of help. And this question is the only hit on Google. Is it a known problem?

Comment: @bradygaster I have the same issue deploying a WebJob to the Australia SouthEast region

Answer (score 1):

Redeploy the Web Site into a different region, it seems the region EAST-US2 does not support WebJobs. 
I deployed it into South Central Us and it works fine there.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following screenshot taken from the Azure Portal shows the regions that can be used to create scheduled jobs:

[image: Regions]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it has much to do with this, but I was experiencing the same issue for a Webjob being published in the Australia East region.

I was trying to publish a scheduled job, but was getting the error:

> Error   14  An error occurred while creating the WebJob schedule: BadRequest: The condition specified by the ETag is not satisfied.

I did notice some restrictions on the webjobs in the free tier (see here -
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/ )

While it doesn't say that scheduled jobs were excluded from the free tier I had suspicions it would have been (it makes sense for scheduled to be excluded from this tier from a MS point of view).

To fix, I simply changed the website tier to Standard, and I've been able to successfully deploy my job.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: WebJobs are available on the Free tier.