# How can I deploy Azure WebJobs with VS2015?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure, azure-webjobs

**Background**

I have a simple WebJob with nothing really in it right now but a `Console.WriteLine` and I tested publishing it to my subscription which worked, kind of - I received a message saying "An error occurred while creating the WebJob schedule: No website could be found which matches the.." but the WebJob seemed to be deployed in the Azure Management Portal (old one). And so I tried to find a solution to this error where one suggestion was to downgrade the [Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish package to 1.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31680673/azure-webjobs-publishing-error).

Unfortunately, this seems to have messed things up even worse. So, now I have two seemingly identical (they are not) "Publish as Azure WebJob.." options available in my project context menu where none of them works.

[image: Two seemingly identical options]

Clicking the first option will tell me that a VS nuget package could not be loaded.

[image: Micrsosoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.Core.Contracts.IWebPublishService]

Clicking the second option will tell me that the version is too old or it will bring me to the Publish dialog, which will eventually tell me the same error message as initially;

> C:..\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.11\tools\webjobs.console.targets(110,5):
>   Error : An error occurred while creating the WebJob schedule: No
>   website could be found which matches the WebSiteName [myWebsite] and
>   WebSiteUrl [http://myWebsite.azurewebsites.net] supplied.

I have tried to clear solution, rebuild, remove & restore all nuget packages, log into my Azure subcription in the Server explorer and explicitly selecting correct subscription before publish, restarting VS, rebooting, both http and https.

I guess the questions I am posing are:

**What is going on here?** Anybody else experiencing this issue? Probable solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Theres a vs extension for deploying webjobs

Comment: Here is the [link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4824551-2660-4afa-aba1-1fcc1673c3d0)

Comment: Maybe not for VS2105 - "This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.", besides, why should it be necessary to use a 3rd-party product to deploy from one Microsoft product to another - where there is an actual Microsoft implementation available?

Comment: You gotta work with what you got

Comment: Ok, thank you so much!

Comment: You need to add a WebApp with the corresponding name. I also found out that if you're using Git integration for CI, you might need to add a dummy Web project to your solution and deploy that with the appropriate link to your webjob.

Comment: I do have a corresponding WebApp named `myWebsite` in this case. If I manually zip my binaries and go into the Azure Portal (classic) I can upload it under the WebApp and it works just fine... but of course, I would like an easier way to deploy than to zip + upload every time.

Comment: @CallumLinington  The link you have given is compatiable with only VS 2012 and VS 2013. I don't find any extension for VS 2015.