# Azure Scheduled Job Fails to Execute

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-scheduler

I had two scheduled jobs running in my developer program benefit subscription.  I had set them up originally using the classic portal.  I set them to run every hour since I am on Free Tier.  Everything was working fine until I had to redeploy the code (console applications)

First problem - I could not find a way to easily update the code for the scheduled jobs so I deleted them and recreated them  I tried to recreate them from the portal, first by creating the WebJob and then by going to the scheduled jobs collection and creating a schedule for the web job.

However each time it runs, it fails with the following error

> Http Action - Response from host 'mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net':
>   'Unauthorized' Response Headers: Date: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 04:07:00 GMT
>
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
>
> WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="site"
>
> Body:        
>   401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid
>   credentials.....

And some other html stuff unrelated to the error

I tried also to deploy the job directly from Visual Studio 2015 (latest update)
however the same result occurs, running the job fails with the same error.

It is my understanding that even on free tier I should be able to run a scheduled job (5 of them) every hour.

Why is it failing and complaining about credentials?

EDIT: The job runs from App Service - WebJobs so there's nothing wrong with the job itself, the code executes correctly, I just can't get it to run from the Scheduler.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507779/publishing-web-app-to-azure-websites-staging-deployment-slot-fails-with-webjob/33521439#33521439

Comment: Have you set up the `Authorization` header in the scheduler job? It needs to contain `Basic <deployment credentials in base 64>` where you need to put the deployment username and password concatenated with a colon `:` (`<username>:<password>`) and base 64-encode it.

Comment: @juunas in the name value pairs? I tried it but it still fails, I put Basic in the name, and for value, I went to this site https://www.base64encode.org/ and put ($username:password) like that with brackets and colon like you said, and encoded  it, and pasted the value into the Value field ....still didn't work

Comment: You need to set the header name to `Authorization` and value to `Basic <base 64-encoded string>`.

Comment: @juunas I tried numerous combinations, with, without brackets, and still no luck - same error "Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the “Access is denied due to invalid credentials” error is happened when you don’t set the Authentication information in your 
Scheduler Job ‘s action settings tag.

The error is like below:
[image]

I suggest you find your webjob’s username and password firstly.

You could find it in the webjob’s properties tag.

Like below:

[image]

Then you could set the user name and password in the action’s setting.

It will work well.

[image]

Comment: It wont let me. It says I need to upgrade my plan. Which is not an option. Also even in free tier we should be able to run 5 scheduled jobs so this does not make sense.

Comment: Documentation is also out of date.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs#a-namecreatescheduledacreate-a-scheduled-webjob-using-the-azure-scheduler "The Azure Portal doesn't yet have the ability to create a scheduled WebJob, but until that feature is added you can do it by using the classic portal"  However this capability has been removed recently from the classic portal.

Comment: Yes, if you want to use the HTTP outbound authorization object in the scheduled collection, you must use the standard collection and above.
Since azure new portal has removed the scheduled webjob instead using the CRON and timertigger. As you say, it need the web application always on.So I think now we don’t have a good way to run the scheduled webjob in the free tier.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to run your schedule based off of a [Cron expression](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2015/06/scheduling-azure-webjobs)? The post highlights how to use the `settings.job` file to provide a schedule to execute on. Here are some [example cron expressions](https://code.google.com/p/ncrontab/wiki/CrontabExamples) for your to figure out if this scenario would work.

Comment: I looked into this, however I think the web jobs in general have a limited lifetime (20 minutes) In order for the CRON expression to work as a scheduler I think you have to enable an option called 'Always On'  but this option is available to Basic or higher level plans.  Hence the need to use the scheduler to trigger it.  The only way it might work is to keep the scm site alive but again that still requires an external trigger - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28905968/1462656

Comment: Oh yes, that's right, I forgot that you were running on the free tier.